# How do we say there is A Turing machine when it does not halt

Tags: turing-machines, turing-test

Generally we will say there is A DFA for a language if we give a string to that DFA and after processing it  it will reach to DFA and DFA more or less stops at final state,so then we say there is a  DFA, and if that string does not reach final state we say there is no DFA

In Contrast

When it is case for Recursively enumerable language how do you say there is a turing machine for a language if it never halts as we don't know whether it halts or not so its like its not reaching any state to be called as turing machine for that language.

Comment: There is no "final state" in a DFA

Comment: There are final states in DFA ,when a string is accepted by any particular DFA it will stop in a particular state that state is called as DFA

Comment: They are called "accepting states" and by no means are a "final" state the DFA will be in. In contrast, the "final states" in a TM will stop the machine when you reach them - Its a totally different concept.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123907/why-does-a-dfa-have-multiple-final-states

Comment: final states and Accepting states are used in same context in DFA ,Like they are one and the same

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a $TM$ for a language is the following:

The language of a TM $M$ is defined as $L(M):=\{w\in \Sigma^* \mid M(w) \text{ halts and accepts}\}$

Now, for a fixed language $L_0$, we say that $M$ is a TM for $L_0$ if $L(M)=L_0$.

Comment: Thank You, But What will say for a instance of a language that doesn't halt for one such particular Turing machine ,Will we say there is a TM or will we say no we do not  have a Turing machine as it doesn't halt

Comment: I Got it we will say there is a Turing Machine from the perspective of strings accepted and for the strings not in the language it may Halt or may Fall in Infinite Loop but we say there is a Turing machine as its accepting those which are in the language ,Correct me if i am Wrong

Comment: Since we are dealing with RE (recursively enumerable) languages, it doesn't matter if the TM rejects or gets stuck in an infinite loop. What we are interested in - is only one thing: that the TM **accepts** *exactly* the language you consider

Comment: Yaa Got it Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*There is a machine* for some language is a shorthand for, either:

- some machine can *accept* the language, or
- some machine can *decide* the language.

They are subtly different things.

When a machine *decides* a language, and you throw a string at it, it is guaranteed to confirm that the string is in the language, when it is, and to confirm that it is *not* in the language, when it is not.

When a machine *accepts* a language, and you throw a string at it, it is guaranteed to confirm that the string is in the language, when it is, and  to *not* produce the verdict that it is in the language, when it is not - but in that case, it may fail to produce any verdict at all.

DFAs always produce a verdict for any string you throw at them: just run the DFA on the string, which will take one step for each character of the string, and when you're done, check whether the DFA is in an accepting state. So DFAs always decide a language, and when we say there is a DFA for a language, we always mean it decides the language.

Not so for TMs. They accept and decide languages differently: they always run until they are in a halting state, and they may never get there. The reason we need to allow this, and that we need to make the distinction between accepting and deciding a language for TMs, is that some languages are [*semidecidable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) (some machine accepts them) but not *decidable* (no machine decides them). So the best we can do, for such languages, is to have a machine that accepts them but does not decide them.